# What is a better way of phrasing this Neo4J Cypher 2 query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query that takes too long to execute:

```
MATCH (s:Person{id:"103"}), s-[rel]-a WITH rel, s 
MATCH c1-[:friend]->s<-[:friend]-c2, c1-[fol:follows]->c2 
RETURN DISTINCT c1,c2;
```

However, when I split it in two:

```
MATCH (s:Person{id:"103"}), s-[rel]-a 
RETURN rel, s;
```

and

```
MATCH (s:Person{id:"103"}), 
c1-[:friend]->s<-[:friend]-c2, c1-[fol:follows]->c2 
RETURN DISTINCT c1,c2;
```

they are much faster.

Why is it that passing rel and s to the next query makes it so much slower?

(I'm asking because that sample query is only a part of a bigger one and I pass on rel and s with the WITH instead of RETURN to the next part of the query)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first cycles for each node and relation found in the first MATCH:

```
MATCH (s:Person{id:"103"}), s-[rel]-a WITH rel, s
```

One row for each relation involving that node. I would use the third query, since rel is never used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try to "profile" the query in Neo4J console, it will give you some clues of how the query actually executed in server.
btw, why would you need to pass the on the "rel" since it never been used